# Ionic 2 Provider Observable Unsubscribing

Tags: ionic2, observable

I am working on an Ionic application and I am having an issue as to when to unsubscribe to observable used in providers. Currently what I am doing is on a page I checking whether or not the use is authenticated before entering the page. Then if they are authenticated I return the users data from firebase. Here is the function used on the page

```
ionViewCanEnter() {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.auth.isBusiness()
    .then(user => {
      this.currentUser = user;
      resolve(true);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.presentToast()
      reject(false)
    });
});
}
```

The functions I call exist in a provider. From the provider I subscribe to my users data from firebase. I am using takeUntil to handle the unsubscription of this observable once i leave the page and call dispose on the provider. My issue is when i try to renavigate to the page i am already unsubscribed from the destroy$ variable. Should I not be unsubscribing from observables from within providers because the same provider is used among pages and not reinitialized or is there something else I need to be doing. Do I need to manually call an init function for the provider whenever I load my page?

```
private destroy$: Subject<any>
 public isBusiness() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.isAuthenticated()
        .then(user => {
          this.userProvider.getUser(user["uid"]).takeUntil(this.destroy$).subscribe(searchedUser => {
            if (searchedUser.userType === "business") {
              resolve(searchedUser);
            } else {
              reject("You are not a business");
            }
          })
        }).catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
  public dispose() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using Subscription as below,

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";
```

Create a variable in the **service** as

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[]=[];
```

When you are subscribing to an Observable push it into your array

```
public isBusiness() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.isAuthenticated()
        .then(user => {
        this.subscriptions
            .push(
                this.userProvider
                    .getUser(user["uid"])
                    .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
                    .subscribe(searchedUser => {
                        if (searchedUser.userType === "business") resolve(searchedUser);
                        else reject("You are not a business");
                    }))
        }).catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

When the page is destroying you can

```
public dispose() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(item=>{
    item.unsusbscribe();
    });
```

}

When destroying that component call the dispose method.

Comment: The problem is the observable is in my provider while you are suggesting to put the array of Subscriptions in the component. The provider will not have access to this list of subscriptions. Are you suggesting passing this list to the provider when entering the page each time?

Comment: @user4717937 creating variable in service

Comment: Should we clear the subscriptions array after dispose is finished?

Comment: yes. when component `ngOnDestroy` call `this.service.dispose()`

Comment: No i mean should i do `this.subscriptions = [];` at the end of the dispose function?